# No RDP access to Azure VM

Tags: azure, rdp

I have a public web server hosted on Azure (Windows Server 2012) which I reconfigured using the ***Best Practice*** option in [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download).  This seems to have disabled some parts of TLS 1.0 are essential for RDP access (oops!).  The only way I know how to re-enable TLS is by changing the registry and rebooting.  Changing the registry is typically done from within an RDP session.

Is there another way to get this working e.g. can we get the Azure VM to run a powershell script at boot?

I still have FTP access and the web server services are running as normal.  I just can't RDP.

I'm fully aware this was my own fault - maybe we need a site called ***AdminFault*** to cater for idiots like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft advised editing the registry manually from another machine on the same network but as this is a stand-alone device on its own network that isn't an option.

They also advise detaching the virtual disk from this VM (we'll call it VM1 with  DiskA), attaching it to another VM (we'll call it VM2).  Then modifying the registry on DiskA from VM2, detaching DiskA from VM2 and reataching it to VM1.  Sure what could go wrong!

I'll try to update this answer when we're successful.

Comment: It sound like it would be easier to add a virtual network if you don't have it yet, assign VM1 to the Vnet, then spin up another VM2 on the same network so they could talk. Then through powershell edit the registry TLS 1.0 settings on VM1 from VM2. (Depends on your powershell remote settings on VM1 though )

Comment: Andreas. . Good suggestion but we went with MS advice. Your idea better as it would have minimised down time.

Comment: We went with detaching the disk in the end.  Microsoft had to do this for us as the steps they outlined included fist making a backup however we didn't have access to that feature so only Microsoft could do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the custom script extension at start-up. details of the extensions are in this link:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/automating-vm-customization-tasks-using-custom-script-extension/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Azure windows custom script extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript) to modify registry value.

If you want to enable TLS 1.0 on Windows Server 2012, you could refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418.aspx#BKMK_SchannelTR_TLS10)
[image]

You could write a PowerShell script to enable TLS 1.0

```
Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server' -name Enabled -value 1
```

Then you could use Azure Custom Extension to execute this cmdlet on Azure Portal. `<Your VM>-->Extensions-->Custom Script Extension`
[image]